# Word break problem with recursion and memorization

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

For practice, I solved Leetcode [139. worbreak](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-break/) question:

> Given a non-empty string s and a dictionary wordDict containing a list of non-empty words, determine if s can be segmented into a space-separated sequence of one or more dictionary words.

I have the solution to use the recursive with in-memory hash table to reduced to duplication calculation. but it seems like works for some case but not all. any suggestions?

```
def wordbreak(self, s, wordDict):
    wordDict = set(wordDict)
    str_map = dict()
    if not s or not wordDict: return False

    def check(s):
        if s in str_map: return str_map[s]
        if s in wordDict:
            str_map[s] = True
            return True
        for i, c in enumerate(s[1:], 1):
            if s[:i] in set(wordDict) and check(s[i:]):
                str_map[s[:i]] = True
        str_map[s] = False
        return False

    return check(s)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    testcase = [
        dict(tc=dict(s='ab', wordDict=['a', 'b']), exp=True),
        dict(tc=dict(s='leetcode', wordDict=['leet', 'code']), exp=True),
        dict(tc=dict(
            s="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab",
            wordDict=["a", "aa", "aaa", "aaaa", "aaaaa", "aaaaaa", "aaaaaaa", "aaaaaaaa", "aaaaaaaaa",
                      "aaaaaaaaaa"]), exp=False),
    ]
    for tc in testcase:
        res = wordbreak(**tc['tc'])
        print(res) # True, True, False
```

Comment: yes. the code works but just have time limit for the third case s='aaaa...'. and seems I already use in-memo but wondering why i still have time limit

Comment: I can't see anything in your code which accounts for the space separators between the words. Are you sure that it implements the spec?

Comment: i use str_map dict to record each substring result. and iterate the string s under recursive function `check`

Comment: I tried to actually test the code and got `TypeError: wordbreak() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`. My best guess as to how to fix it (remove the `self` parameter) results in output `False` `False` `False`, which while it seems to meet the spec does not correspond to the unused `exp` keys or the comment after `print(res)`. I am therefore voting to close as "Not working code".

Comment: that `self` is due to the way the leetcode system works. The OP should have removed it, but closing the question because of that seems a bit harsh.

Comment: @MaartenFabré, that's just one of the problems. If it had been the only problem and I had found a simple fix then I would instead write an answer and mention it there.

Comment: it also lacks a `return True` after `str_map[s[:i]] = True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## bug

```
def wordBreak(self, s, wordDict):
    wordDict = set(wordDict)
    str_map = dict()
    if not s or not wordDict: return False

    def check(s):
        if s in str_map: return str_map[s]
        if s in wordDict:
            str_map[s] = True
            return True
        for i, c in enumerate(s[1:], 1):
            if s[:i] in set(wordDict) and check(s[i:]):
                str_map[s[:i]] = True
                return True  # <== you forgot this one
        str_map[s] = False
        return False

    return check(s)
```

passes all cases in 48ms

## set(wordDict)

No need to do this in each iteration if you do that at the start of the algorithm

## `c`

this variable is not used. Python convention uses `_` for variables that are not used

## reinventing the wheel (cache)

Python is *batteries included*

so you can as easily use `functools.lru_cache` instead of implementing your own cache:

```
from functools import lru_cache

def wordBreak(self, s, wordDict):
    wordDict = set(wordDict)
    if not s or not wordDict: return False
    @lru_cache(None)
    def check(s):
        if s in wordDict:
            return True
        for i, _ in enumerate(s[1:], 1):
            if s[:i] in wordDict and check(s[i:]):
                return True
        return False
    return check(s)
```

passes in 36ms

---

## alternative version

instead of running over the string, you can also try to build a graph of all occurrences of the words in `wordDict`, and then look if you can find a path from `0` to `len(s)`

### all chars in `wordDict`

you can check whether all chars in `s` appear in a word in `wordDict`

```
def validate_all_chars(text, words):
    all_chars = set()
    for word in words:
        all_chars.update(word)
    return all_chars.issuperset(text)
```

or with `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
def validate_all_chars(text, words):
    all_chars = set(chain.from_iterable(words))
    return all_chars.issuperset(text)
```

### occurrences:

Unfortunately, `re.finditer` and `re.findall` only give non-overlapping occurrences, so we can't use them here. So we'll have to build our own finder:

```
def find_occurrences(pattern: str, text: str):
    idx = 0
    while True:
        idx = text.find(pattern, idx)
        if idx == -1:
            return
        yield idx, idx + len(pattern)
        idx += 1
```

### build a graph

```
from collections import defaultdict
def build_span_graph(text, words):
    all_spans = defaultdict(set)
    spans = (find_occurrences(word, text) for word in words)
    for span in spans:
        for begin, end in span:
            all_spans[begin].add(end)
    return all_spans
```

### walk the graph:

```
def find_path(spans, length, begin=0, visited=None):
    visited = set() if visited is None else visited
    visited.add(begin)
    ends = spans[begin]
    return length in ends or any(
        find_path(spans, length=length, begin=new_begin, visited=visited)
        for new_begin in ends
        if new_begin not in visited and new_begin in spans
    )
```

Here you can try to optimize a bit by first visiting the furthest ends, but that is only marginally useful

## main:

```
def wordBreak(s: "str", wordDict: "List[str]") -> "bool":
    if not validate_all_chars(s, wordDict):
        return False

    spans = build_span_graph(s, wordDict)

    return find_path(s, wordDict)
```

Comment: so nice to know functools.lru_cache

Comment: Actually `find_path` reports a bug on the return statement: `TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not list` .  And I can see why it wouldn't work, as `length` is the `wordDict` the first time it's called.